# Web2Lead RecordType

Tags: record-type, leads, web2lead, form

i have a pdf order form that i would like to use to submit web2lead data to my production org, i have it setup in sandbox and have gotten all fields to submit properly except for *recordType* which is setup the same way as *oid*; in a hidden field that submits with the other fields. i have gone through a few other articles such as [this success story](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A0000019TdYQAU). where the user places the recordtypeID inside a hidden field. i have also changed the Lead Settings to "Keep the Existing record Type" on advisement of [This Salesforce Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005177&type=1).

is there something else i am missing? am i not submitting the form correctly? or am i missing the correct field name? its something small im sure!

---

### Form:

[image: Oderform]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like your form isn't coded correctly. The field name is `recordType`, not `recordtype`. Always pay attention to capitalization when creating a web-to-lead or web-to-case form.

Comment: i had to change all form fields to lowercase or they dont submit at all. ive tried recordType as well.

Comment: @BryanCerrati No, all of the field names must be *precisely* capitalized or it won't work. Note that, for example, `tour_description__c` is also not written correctly. You need to use the web-to-lead form generator to get the correct names. Custom fields are typically written with a name/id of `00NXXXXXXXXXXXX` (X is a placeholder value here), also case-sensitive.

Comment: so if i change the field to its generated field name then `recordType` will work? because they work correctly now.

Comment: @BryanCerrati If you're not using the generated form, you cannot be assured that anything else will work in the future.

Comment: thank you. recordType now works, will edit form to work in completion. thank you again.